# How to convert xpath location to pixel

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm wondering is it possible to convert an xpath location or an element id to a pixel location (x,y) using java?

I've looked in various locations but cant get a concise and straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the element and use [`getLocation()` method](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getLocation()):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my_id")); 
System.out.println(element.getLocation());
```

Note that `getLocation()` returns a "Point" (coordinates of a left top corner of an element).

Comment: How would I use these pixels in a method?For example the print outputs 217,1045 I want to use these coordinates in a method that uses a drag and drop robot.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the complete program.

```
  public void getCoordinates(){
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));

  Point location = element.getLocation();
  int x = location.getX();
  int y = location.getY();
  System.out.println("Coordinates of an element is : " + x + " and " + y);
 }
```